Django + Apache2 + React doesn't work
it consists Apache2 linked with Django as backend(WSGI), and React as frontend. But it returns only '403 Forbidden' with symbol AH01630 in the error log. Also Apache2 version is 2.4.58.
A part of apache configuration sites-available/default-ssl.conf:
WSGIDaemonProcess serve python-home=/venv/vee python-path=/venv/pub/proj/serve/serve
WSGIScriptAlias /api /venv/pub/proj/serve/serve/wsgi.py

<Directory /venv/pub/proj/serve/serve>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /venv/pub/proj/serve/front/build>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
</Directory>

'sites-available/react.conf`:
DocumentRoot /venv/pub/proj/serve/front/build

<Directory /venv/pub/proj/serve/front/build>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Django project is placed on /venv/pub/proj/serve, and React project is /venv/pub/proj/serve/front.
Previously, the server was configured Apache2 and Django, not React, so then Django WSGI settings are not problem.
I want to know why it seems to conflict Apache2 configurations between default-ssl.conf and react.conf. If WSGI is disabled, React app is shown.

I solved.
ServerName should have unique value each configuration files. If frontend and backend are in one server, replace ServerName or Listening port to another.
